# Using imported asynchronous method with promises in main entry point

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm creating a Node.js module with an asynchronous method - a simple HTTP GET request. Here is the code:

```
//mymodule.js
var https = require('https');

function getSomething(url_str)
{
    var callback_fn = function(response){
        var body = '';

        response.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });

        response.on('end', function () {
            //console.log(body);
            return body;
        });
    };

    return https.request(url_str, callback_fn).end();
}

var module_obj = {
    getSome: getSomething
};

module.exports = module_obj;
```

This module is called by my app.js - a web server - like so:

```
//app.js
var myModule = require('./mymodule');
var http = require('http');
var qs = require('querystring');

var server_fn = function(request, response){
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Request-Method', '*');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'OPTIONS, GET');
    response.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
    if ( request.method === 'OPTIONS' ) {
        response.writeHead(200);
        response.end();
        return;
    }

    if (request.method == 'POST') {
        var body = '';

        request.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;

            // Too much POST data, kill the connection!
            // 1e6 === 1 * Math.pow(10, 6) === 1 * 1000000 ~~~ 1MB
            if (body.length > 1e6)
                request.connection.destroy();
        });

        request.on('end', function () {
            var post = qs.parse(body),
                post_url = post.url,
                post_method = post.method;

            var promise_flow = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
                if(post_method === 'get_me_something')
                {
                    response_str = myModule.getSome(post_url);
                    resolve(response_str);
                }
                else
                {
                    resolve('nothing');
                }
            });

            promise_flow
                .then(function(response){
                response.write(response);
                response.end();
                return;
            }).catch(function(error){
                response.write(error);
                response.end();
                return;
            })

        });
    }
};
var http_server = http.createServer(server_fn);
http_server.listen(2270);
console.log("server listening on 2270");
```

So basically, I start things up via `node app.js`, and then I post the URL, and then the module should fetch the Web page and then return the content.

Unfortunately, I'm getting the following error:

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: First argument must be a string or Buffer
```

I believe this is because the response I'm getting from my modules `getSomething` method is `false`, as opposed to the content of the requested Web page.

I know I can fix this by moving the `https.get` operation from `mymodule.js` and putting it inline with `app.js`, and then calling `resolve` on end, but I'd like to keep the current module setup.

Is there a workaround to get the asynchronous method in the imported module to work with the existing promise chain as setup?

**UPDATE**

After further review, I noticed that I wasn't quite running things the right way. I updated the code as follows:

```
//...
var promise_flow = new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
    if(post_method === 'get_me_something')
    {
        myModule.getSome(post_url)
            .then(function(data){
                resolve(data);
            })
            .catch(function(err){
                reject(err);
            });
    }
    else
    {
        resolve('nothing');
    }
});
//...
```

This way, I think it fits with the true spirit of Promises.

Comment: Shouldn't `myModule.getSomething(post_url);` be `myModule.getSome(post_url);`, or is it a typo? Because you export `getSome` and not `getSomething`. It must be a typo, because the code would just fail with something like `myModule.getSomething` is not a function

Comment: [`end` doesn't return anything](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback). What are you trying to `return` from the asynchronous `getSomething` function?

Comment: @SamuelBolduc Yes, it was a typo. Fixed now.

Comment: Kindly explain downvote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getSomething` function doesn't return a promise. Make it returns a promise, and fulfill the promise in `response.on('end')`.

```
function getSomething(url_str)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var callback_fn = function(response){
            var body = '';

            response.on('data', function (data) {
                body += data;
            });

            response.on('end', function () {
                //console.log(body);
                resolve(body);
            });
        };
        https.request(url_str, callback_fn).end();
    });
}
```

Then in your main file, call it like this : `myModule.getSomething(post_url).then(resolve);`.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot. And it actually works without the suggested update to the main file

Comment: That's true, I didn't think about it, but `response_str` is an unfulfilled promise it works as `resolve` knows how to handle unfulfilled promises. Side note: `response_str` becomes an ambiguous variable name now that it contains a promise and not a string!